# 2D output on Lineal regression model

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I'm getting the following error from my code:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
> array=99.
> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Here is the code used:

```
#importing libraries

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

Physical_activity_df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/LW_docs/Physical_activity_nopass.xlsx')

prediction_df = Physical_activity_df[['Activity_Score','Calories']]
prediction_df.plot(kind='scatter', x= 'Activity_Score', y= 'Calories')
plt.show()

#change to df variables
activity_score = pd.DataFrame(prediction_df['Activity_Score'])
calories = pd.DataFrame(prediction_df['Calories'])

lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = lm.fit(activity_score,calories)

#predict new values for calories (FROM HERE COMES THE ERROR)
activity_score_new = 99
calories_predict = model.predict(activity_score_new)
calories_predict
```

Any idea about how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Error says it all. 2D array(like) expected. `model.predict([[99]])` should work. See [sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.predict](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.predict)

Comment: Thanks @StefanB, it's working!